# Conditional deciding fields of content in a dynamic block

Tags: terraform

In the root module, I have:

```
  dynamic "settings" {
    for_each = var.settings
    content {
      name    = settings.value["name"]
      type    = settings.value["type"]
      id      = settings.value["id"]
      template = settings.value["template"]
      design = settings.value["design"]
    }
  }
```

From the calling module `design` and `template` fields sometimes will be there sometime not, e.g.:

```
  settings = [
    { "type" = "global", "id" = "123", "name" = "asfasff" },
    { "type" = "global", "id" = "123", "name" = " asfasff " },
    { "type" = "global", "id" = "123", "name" = " asfasff ", "design"="abc" }
  ]
```

How can I decide this at the runtime? I basically looking for a terraform laternative of this:

```
dynamic "settings" {
    for_each = var.settings

if lookup(settings[i], "design", default) != default    
    content {
      name    = settings.value["name"]
      type    = settings.value["type"]
      id      = settings.value["id"]
      template = settings.value["template"]
      design = settings.value["design"]
    }
else
    content {
      name    = settings.value["name"]
      type    = settings.value["type"]
      id      = settings.value["id"]
    }    
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

For any value you don't really want to set, pass a `null`.

For example:

```
  dynamic "settings" {
    for_each = var.settings
    content {
      name    = lookup(settings.value, "name", null)
      type    = lookup(settings.value, "type", null)
      id      = lookup(settings.value, "id", null)
      template = lookup(settings.value, "template", null)
      design = lookup(settings.value, "design", null)
    }
  }
```

In the above code only the values that actually exist in the `settings.value` map will be set on the dynamic block, all the settings that don't exist will be set to `null` which Terraform (as of verision 0.12) treats as if the value is unset or doesn't exist.

Comment: `settings.value is null Invalid value for "inputMap" parameter: argument must not be null.`
It throws this error while planning.

Comment: That error suggests that at least one of the elements of `var.settings` is null itself, and so `lookup` can't lookup into it. A more general way to get the "use a fallback if this isn't possible" effect might be `try(settings.value.name, null)`, although if `settings` being null isn't what you intended then probably better to figure out why that is than to paper over it with `try`.

Comment: @MartinAtkins that's absolutely true. However I don't see how that would be possible using the code in my answer, given the way terraform dynamic blocks work, so I wonder if the actual code generating the error looks different.